# Java 8 Iterate List inside an list and stream.map()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am wondering if there is a single line option for this issue.

I have a bean like,

```
public class DataA {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private List<String> accountNumberName;
}
```

Sample value in `DataA` is

`name="user1",email="user@a.b.com",accountNumberName=["100", "101", "102"]` etc..

I have a map of account number and Name `Map<String, String> accountNumberNameMap`
Sample data in `accountNumberNameMap` is like,

`{"100"="Account A", "101" = "Account B", "102" = "Account C"}`

I want to convert `DataA` to `name="user1",email="user@a.b.com",accountNumberName=["100 - Account A", "101 - Account B", "102 - Account C"]`

I have a collection of DataA `List<DataA>` want to convert all my `accountNumberName` inside the 'List'  to have `account number - Account name` using `accountNumberNameMap`.

I can do it by using couple of loops and then convert account Number to account number - account Name. Wondering if there is a easy way in Java8 stream to do it.

Comment: What do you want to do when the map doesn't contain the account number?

Comment: I think `accountNumberNameMap.getOrDefault(acc, "")` should handle it.

Comment: the question wasn't how to code it, but what the behavior should be. So, your answer is to use a blank string, right, like a left-join works?

Comment: Yes.. I need an empty string. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind modifying the instances in the list directly, you can use `forEach` combined with `replaceAll` (I assumed I could access the `accountNumberName` for simplicity but you can easily change it also via a setter).

```
list.forEach(d -> d.accountNumberName.replaceAll(acc -> acc + " - " + accountNumberNameMap.getOrDefault(acc, "")));
```

If you don't want to modify the existing instances, it can be done this way (assuming a copy constructor exists):

```
list.replaceAll(d -> new DataA(d.name, d.email, d.accountNumberName.stream().map(name -> name + " - " + accountNumberNameMap.getOrDefault(name, "")).collect(toList())));
```

(and then if you don't want to modify the original list, just stream/collect over it instead of using `replaceAll`)

Comment: I wanted to update the instances in the list directly.. Thanks for quick reply.